# How to add a text box in Chart.JS

Tags: chart.js

I have created a simple Bar Chart in Chart.JS and all looks good. I now need to add a text box to the chart with rounded corners such as in the example below

[image: Chart with text box]

I have tried the annotation plugin, but that only seems to add boxes and lines, not text. I don't want to overwrite defaults as I have several charts on my page, and only this one is to contain the text.

Is this possible?

Thanks